# recaptcha v2 explicit render basic setup: invalid-input-response

Tags: recaptcha

I am trying to implement google recaptcha v2.  I have two small example files: recaptcha.html and recaptcha.php

recaptcha.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
      <script>
        var showRecaptcha = function() {
        Recaptcha.create("6LfCLRQTAAAAAFyZ4QZ6mMl7bu2syW9yH813kHnG",
                         'captchadiv',
                         {
                             size: "compact",
                             callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
                         }
        );
      }
      </script>
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=showRecaptcha&render=explicit"
         async defer>
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <form id="rmForm" role="form" action="recaptcha.php" 
             method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
         <div  id="captchadiv"></div>
     </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

and recaptcha.php:

```
<?php 
$secret = "6LfCLRQTAAAAABgzTkyDJMxEo-HTnEEr8xBEv1wE";
if(isset($_REQUEST["recaptcha_response_field"]))  {
    // we are processing a remove request with a recaptcha
    $captcha=$_REQUEST["recaptcha_response_field"];
    var_dump($captcha);
    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?" .
"secret=$secret&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

}
if($response.'success'==true)   {  echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';   }
var_dump($response);
?>
```

This is also available at http://gps-photo.com/recaptcha.html.
As you will see, if you try it, it always gives 'invalid-input-response'.  Seems to me that it should work, so I am obviously confused.

Can someone help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing **recaptcha_ajax.js** with **recaptcha.js** and using *render* to display instead of *create* solved the problem.